# Can I write reverse div operator?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a mathematical equation and How can I find the it's reverse ?
My equation:

```
var 
x,y:integer;
begin
//example x=1234;
x-(x div 100):=y
end;
```

after the code I konw "y" how can I find the "x"?(1234)

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can't. Since `div` does integer division, there are potentially many inputs that can/will produce the same result. Starting from that result, and of those inputs is an equally likely possibility as the original input. For example:

```
175 div 7 = 25
176 div 7 = 25
177 div 7 = 25
178 div 7 = 25
179 div 7 = 25
180 div 7 = 25
181 div 7 = 25
```

Starting from 25, any of those numbers from 175 to 181 would be an equally viable answer.